# Conflicting types for operator overload (XCode 5.0)

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, operator-overloading, conflict

A piece of code from my C++ maths library has stopped working since updating to XCode 5.0.

It declares some operator overload functions which respond differently depending on the parameter types passed. Here's the code (all in a .h file):

```
#ifndef __RMKit__RMVector3f__
#define __RMKit__RMVector3f__

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {//start extern "C"
#endif

union _RMVector3f {
    struct {float x,y,z;};
    struct {float r,g,b;};
    struct {float s,t,p;};
    float v[3];
};
typedef union _RMVector3f RMVector3f;

#pragma mark - math operator overloads prototypes
#ifdef __cplusplus //only declare operator overloads if using C++
static __inline__ RMVector3f operator + (RMVector3f lhs, RMVector3f rhs);
static __inline__ RMVector3f operator + (RMVector3f lhs, float rhs);
static __inline__ RMVector3f operator - (RMVector3f lhs, RMVector3f rhs);
static __inline__ RMVector3f operator - (RMVector3f lhs, float rhs);

#pragma mark - math operator overload implementations
static __inline__ RMVector3f operator + (RMVector3f lhs, RMVector3f rhs)
{
    RMVector3f tmp;
    tmp.x = lhs.x+rhs.x;
    tmp.y = lhs.y+rhs.y;
    tmp.z = lhs.z+rhs.z;
    return tmp;
}

static __inline__ RMVector3f operator + (RMVector3f lhs, float rhs)
{
    RMVector3f tmp;
    tmp.x = lhs.x+rhs;
    tmp.y = lhs.y+rhs;
    tmp.z = lhs.z+rhs;
    return tmp;
}

static __inline__ RMVector3f operator - (RMVector3f lhs, RMVector3f rhs)
{
    RMVector3f tmp;
    tmp.x = lhs.x-rhs.x;
    tmp.y = lhs.y-rhs.y;
    tmp.z = lhs.z-rhs.z;
    return tmp;
}

static __inline__ RMVector3f operator - (RMVector3f lhs, float rhs)
{
    RMVector3f tmp;
    tmp.x = lhs.x-rhs;
    tmp.y = lhs.y-rhs;
    tmp.z = lhs.z-rhs;
    return tmp;
}
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}//end extern "C"
#endif

#endif /* defined(__RMKit__RMVector3f__) */
```

The compiler (LLVM 5.0) is giving me errors such as:

```
Conflicting types for 'operator+'
Conflicting types for 'operator-'
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Could we have an [sscce](http://sscce.org/). There is not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: What is the definition of `RMVector3f`? What is the complete error message?

Comment: Also, unfortunately that is the only error I get from the compiler :(

Comment: The header which I've included above reproduces the problem entirely. Thus it includes valid code and complies with SSCCEE. I have also described the entire problem and the only error logs I get from XCode. Please take this question off hold, as I feel it is a valid and complete question!!!!!!

Comment: I can confirm the header does reproduce the problem for me. Saving it in `test.cpp` and running `clang test.cpp` shows errors like : `conflicting types for 'operator+'` (I came here because I have a similar problem with Chipmunk Physics)

Comment: Also the same code compiles fine under Xcode 4.6.3

Comment: Just thought I'd mention (in the hope that others may find this useful @Taum)that I've spoken to an Apple engineer about this, it seems that the new compiler doesn't need the 'extern "C"' stuff. If you comment out the start/end extern C it should work fine. Also - it's pretty annoying that this got closed as not a valid question when it clearly is.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I forgot about that problem but ended up solving it by moving the operator overloads outside of the `extern C` block but inside a `#ifdef __cplusplus`. It made sense to me that `extern C` would disable name mangling and thus mess with function overloads, however I am a total newbie in C++ so that may not be a satisfying explanation to others ;)